# Printing with SP-213w

Tags: printing, ricoh

I have a Ricoh SP 213w printer, connected to my machine with a cable. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit

When I print PDF, sometimes it works. Sometimes it prints out garbage.

How could I make it consistently print a PDF correctly, rather than garbage (attached)

Example of Garbage

[image: Example of printed garbage]

Printer Settings

[image: Printer Settings]

Comment: this printer does not get a mention on Open Printing; http://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Ricoh; the manufacturers seem to only offer a Connection Utility; http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re2/model/sp213w/sp213w.htm and the printer does not get a mention in the Ubuntu driver list; so it seems to be largely unsupported; sadly

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using the Generic PCL 3 printer driver. Try changing that to the Generic PCL 6/PCL XL.

That's the one that's recommended, and I can confirm it works fine for me.